# Check if favicon exist locally chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How do I check if the favicon exists in chrome://favicon and if does not exist feed from url. Both URLs works fine just I'm having a problem with checking the image from the local path as non of the JS libraries for checking if image exist works with google local path? Thanks

```
var getFavicon = function (bookmarkUrl) {
  if (validUrl(bookmarkUrl) == true) {
    var localfavicon = 'chrome://favicon/' + bookmarkUrl
    $.get(localfavicon).done(function () {
      return localfavicon
    }).fail(function () {
      return 'http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=' + encodeURIComponent(bookmarkUrl)
    })
  }
}
```

I found this interesting approach but there might be something better.

```
function setFavicon(a, b, c, d) {
    d ? a.attr('src', 'chrome://favicon/' + b) : c ? a.attr('src', c) : window.setTimeout(function() {
        a.attr('src', 'http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=' + encodeURIComponent(b))
    }, 200)
}
```

Comment: Well, you can convert the result into a data URL and compare it to that of the default icon that you can retrieve at the start of your extension by querying a nonexistent URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm you mean compare base 64 (binary) version?